# Angular 2: Place index.html as custom location

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Is it possible to place index.html in a custom location after build?
(I require this so that I can place this index.html in templates folder of django)
Currently it is placed in root of dist folder.

If I eject the angular app, I am able to do this

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      "template": "./src/index.html",
      "filename": "../templates/main/index.html",
      ...
})
```

Is it possible to do it in angular-cli.json? 
Or I would have to define a postbuild step?
(Actually I tried defining a post build step, to cp from dist folder to custom location, but dist folder location is derived from .angular-cli.json and postbuild is an attr of package.json)

Thanks for the help

Comment: yes and you also have to move all the generated files with it

Answer (score 0):

You can modify `.angular-cli.json` and put your path in `outDir` property

```
"outDir": "templates/main",
```

this changes the `build` directory

Edit: For that you need to define an npm script

```
"build":" "ng build"
```

and add the postbuild script:

```
"postbuild": "copy ./build/index.html ./yourFolder/",
```

The `postBuild` runs after the `build` is complete.

Comment: This changes the entire output dir. I need the output dir to be the same, just index.html to be copied somewhere else

Comment: Added the required chages

Comment: Yes, and I tried the same thing as I mentioned in question. But the issue is, the source location for the copy, is derived by "outputDir" in angular-cli. Other than hard coding it I dont see any other option.